# Integer linear programming program does not behave as expected

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pulp

I have the following integer linear programming problem which assigns values as expected, but when I add certain constraints, the objective function seems to become vacuous. I am not sure what to make of it. I am using python to solve the problem.

**Non Vacuous formulation**

```
score12 = 1
score21 = -1
C       = 1000000

maximize  : (w12 - s12) * score12 + (w21 - s21) * score21

subject to:
            d12 = x2 - x1
            d21 = x1 - x2

            d12 - w12*C <= 0
            d21 - w21*C <= 0

            d12 + (1 - w12)*C > 0
            d21 + (1 - w21)*C > 0

            d12 + s12*C      >= 0
            d21 + s21*C      >= 0

            0 <= xi <= 1      , continuous
            0 <= wij, sij <= 1, integer
```

The objective function is as expected:

```
MAXIMIZE
-1*s_12 + 1*s_21 + 1*w_12 + -1*w_21 + 0
```

And the solution is as expected:

```
('d_12', '= ', 0.0)
('d_21', '= ', 0.0)
('s_12', '= ', 0.0)
('s_21', '= ', 1.0)
('w_12', '= ', 1.0)
('w_21', '= ', 0.0)
('x_1', '= ', 0.0)
('x_2', '= ', 0.0)
```

But when I add the following constraints, or just either one:

```
d12 - (1 - s12)*C < 0 
d21 - (1 - s21)*C < 0
```

Python changes the objective function to:

```
MAXIMIZE
0*__dummy + False
SUBJECT TO
... omited
```

I'm not what to make of it, the solution becomes vacuous:

```
('__dummy', '= ', None)
('d_12', '= ', 0.0)
('d_21', '= ', 0.0)
('s_12', '= ', 1.0)
('s_21', '= ', 1.0)
('w_12', '= ', 1.0)
('w_21', '= ', 1.0)
('x_1', '= ', 0.0)
('x_2', '= ', 0.0)
```

Comment: The additional constraints make the feasible set empty?

Comment: the way I saw it is that: d12 - (1-s12)*C < 0 implies either: d12 = 0 and s12 = 0, or d12 = 1 and s12 = 0. d12 = 0 implies x2 = x1, d12 = 1 implies x2 = 1. But neither case contradicts the other constraints. In fact the vacuous solutionm, we see x2 = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not analyze your constraints but here is some comment on what kind of problem there might be.

You are using this to define a constraint:

```
d12 - (1 - s12)*C < 0
```

- In Linear Programming, there are only inequalities of the form `<=` and `>=` (`==` may be constructed by these; ignoring numerical difficulties); everything else is just not natural (not much sense in regards to the math)
- pulp-or only defines the mentioned operators above; but not `<` and `>` [link; scroll to bottom; also see next image from the docs](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp)

[image]

**Pulp is not that robust about wrong usage of the library and usually and silently overwrites the objective when some badly formed constraint is added** (This might be the case here). Maybe you will find some experiences like that in pulp's [issue-tracker](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues)

Consider using the Constraint-class and not using overloaded-operators.